# c# WinForm Grid cells selection algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, winforms

I have developed a C# Win Form calendar for an app used to make reservations.
I do not like the way the selection of the cells (the days) happens. As for now I can handle the use of ctrl and selection of ranges by keeping the shift key + left mouse buttons.
What I would like is a more Excel-like experience because I know users are used to it is it is more intuitive.

I would like to kindly ask you if you now any open source piece of code I can check out in order to better understand a pattern to handle cells selection in relation to the use of ctrl, shift and left mouse button.

Thx folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was developing something like what you already explained after long research I did it using syncfusion library.

https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/scheduler/getting-started

They have commercial version and they recently add community license you can use it for free from here
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense.

you can find alot of ready made features and you can add your touch if you want by override any available feature or add new one.